# How to increase temperature of the condenser part in a refrigeration cycle?

Tags: refrigeration

I have made a refrigeration system at my home. I am using r134a as the refrigerant.

[image]
I want to achieve a temperature of about 70-degree Celcius in the condenser part and 0-degree Celcius in the evaporator part.
(Currently, I think I am able to achieve 30-degree Celcius in the condenser part and about -10 degree Celcius in the evaporator part.)

In order to achieve so, I was thinking to decrease the length of the condenser coil and increase the evaporator coil length.

Is it possible to achieve such temperature as mentioned above?

Comment: The temperatures are controlled by the characteristics of the fluid ie phase changes.

Comment: Not by doing those things, no.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to increase the temperature is to increase the pressure of the pump output/condenser.  This is because the temperature is directly related to the pressure.  The condenser takes heat out and turns the refrigerant to liquid at that pressure  (the pump and condenser are just increasing the boiling point).  A phase diagram of R134a will show you the required pressure, which looks to be about 300 psi.

Comment: @PhilSweet, lol, consider it a vapor pump then.  I understand what's vapor and liquid in a refrigeration cycle.

Answer (score -1):

Partially cover the condenser with insulation, or partially block the fan air flow.

Comment: Hi, your answer would look much better with more explanation. :-)